# How to access variable in PHP callable closure function?

Tags: php

Considering the following PHP code:

```
class Vacation 
{
  protected $onSuccess;
  protected $friend;

  public function onSuccess(callable $callback): self
  {
    $this->onSuccess = $callback;
    return $this;
  }

  public function go()
  {
    echo 'gone' . PHP_EOL;

    $this->friend = 'John';

    call_user_func($this->onSuccess, $this->friend);
  }
}

(new Vacation())
  ->onSuccess(function(){
    echo 'to the beach' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'with ' . $friend . PHP_EOL; // this doesn't work, $this or self either
  })
  ->go();
```

Is it possible to access the `$friend` variable in any way from the closure above?
While it's clear that one can pass variable(s) to the `call_user_func` function, my question is how to retrieve them on the other side, in the `onSuccess` function, which exists outside the `Vacation` class.

And quick follow-up: is there a valid property type for `$onSuccess` in the `Vacation` class if it registering an instance variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already executing the closure with arguments:

```php
call_user_func($this->onSuccess, $this->friend);
```

All you are missing is to include that argument in the closure's signature:

```php
(new Vacation())
  ->onSuccess(function ($friend) {
        echo 'to the beach' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'with ' . $friend . PHP_EOL;
  })
  ->go();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you know about the property type, if any, that is valid on the Vacation class, for the `onSuccess` variable?

Answer (score 0):

The Manider solution is fine but you can use this kind of snippet

```
<?php
class Vacation {
protected $onSuccess;
protected $friend;

public function onSuccess( callable $callback ): self {
    $this->onSuccess = $callback;
    return $this;
}

public function getFriend( ) {
    return $this->friend;
}

public function go( ) {
    echo 'gone' . PHP_EOL;
    $this->friend = 'John';
    call_user_func( $this->onSuccess, $this );
}
}

(new Vacation())->onSuccess( function ( $vacation ) {
  echo 'to the beach' . PHP_EOL;
  echo 'with ' . $vacation->getFriend() . PHP_EOL; // this works
  echo 'on a ' . get_class( $vacation ) . PHP_EOL; // also possible to access the object instance
} )->go();
```

EDIT
In the call_user_func we pass "$this" as argument, so we pass the instantiated Vacation class.
Then, when we do the chaining, we are creating a new instance of Vacation, telling to register the onSuccess callback which become a instance variable called $onSuccess ($this->onSuccess = $callback) which is a function as defined inside the argument of calling onSuccess.
At this point the new Vacation has been initialized with the function in the protected variable $onSuccess. We then call go().
The go function does an echo, set the protected variable $friend to "John", then calls the function saved in $this->onSuccess passing to this function "her self".
Now the php goes inside the defined function and so does the first echo, the second and here we can use $vacation->getFriend() to access the protected variable.

Comment: Please add some explanation for your solution